# How to output rows of CSV file whose values in columns are equal to those specified in standard input

Tags: python, csv

For my HW I need to output the rows whose values are equal to those in the specified column of the CSV file. The header needs to be output as it is even if there are no rows. 
The column number is specified in the first line of standard input and its value on the second line of standard input. The example of input:

```
2
ACampus
Name,Campus,LabName
Yuzu Mori,ACampus,Laboratory of Omics
Yuki Toi,BCampus,Laboratory of RNA Function
Yo Aa,CCampus,Laboratory of Viral Infectious Diseases 
Yu Ya,ACampus,Laboratory of Functional Genetics
Su Yo,BCampus,Laboratory of Cellular Function
```

The example of output:

```
Name,Campus,LabName
Yuzu Mori,ACampus,Laboratory of Omics
Yu Ya,ACampus,Laboratory of Functional Genetics
```

I tried to solve this problem like that.

```
#!usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import csv

data = sys.stdin.readlines()

column_to_be_matched = int(data.pop(0))
word_to_be_matched = data.pop(0)

col_headers = data.pop(0)

print(col_headers)

for row in csv.reader(data):
    if row[column_to_be_matched] == word_to_be_matched: 
       print(row)
```

The program prints col_headers but it does not prints rows with the values I need. How else can I access the values in rows specified through standard input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your "if" condition.  There are two reasons 1) python starts with zero index so column 2 means row[1]   2) readlines() have newlines (\n) on it so you have to remove them

```
Old: if row[column_to_be_matched] == word_to_be_matched: 
New: if row[column_to_be_matched-1] == word_to_be_matched.rstrip('\n'):
```

sample output:

```
     Name,Campus,LabName

    ['Yuzu Mori', 'ACampus', 'Laboratory of Omics']
    ['Yu Ya', 'ACampus', 'Laboratory of Functional Genetics']
```

Comment: one follow up silly question. How can I remove the empty row between Name,Campus, LabName and the rest of output?

Comment: change col_headers = data.pop(0)  to col_headers = data.pop(0).rstrip('\n')